# I m trying to link the img modal box to the img i m clicking at but it wont work

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap, slider, bootstrap-modal

I managed to make a bootstrap3 modal box as a img slider to my thumbnails. 
the only leftover problem i have is that if i click on a img it the slider always begins SOMEWHERE.. not at the img i clicked on. 
Please Help me!!!
Here's my code:

`<div class="container"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          <div class="row">
            <h1>Zeichnungen</h1>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 1" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/1.jpg"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 2" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/2.jpg"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 3" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/3.jpg"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 4" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/4.jpg"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 5" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/5.jpg"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 6" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/6.jpg"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 7" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/7.jpg"></a></div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Image 8" href="#"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/8.jpg"></a></div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>`

`

```
    <!-- Modal-->       
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" style="display: none;" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modalCarousel" class="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item" title="Image 1">
                            <h3 class="modal-title">Image 1</h3>
                            <a href="#" title="Image 1"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/1.jpg"></a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item " title="Image 2">
                            <h3 class="modal-title">Image 2</h3>
                            <a href="#" title="Image 2">
                                <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/2.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" title="Image 3"><h3 class="modal-title">Image 3</h3>
                            <a href="#" title="Image 3">
                                <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/3.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" title="Image 4"><h3 class="modal-title">Image 4</h3>
                            <a href="#" title="Image 4">
                                <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/4.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" title="Image 5"<h3 class="modal-title">Image 5</h3>
                            <a href="#" title="Image 5">
                                <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/5.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" title="Image 6"<h3 class="modal-title">Image 6</h3>
                            <a href="#" title="Image 6">
                                <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/6.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" title="Image 7"<h3 class="modal-title">Image 7</h3>
                            <a href="#" title="Image 7">
                                <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/7.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item" title="Image 8"<h3 class="modal-title">Image 8</h3>
                            <a href="#" title="Image 8">
                                <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/8.jpg">
                            </a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#modaCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
                    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#modalCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <!-- Modal end-->`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the thumbnails link to an image within the slideshow, you'll have to link those thumbnails with the data attributes for the modal target and the slide it should reference. Documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Example:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
  <a title="Image 3" href="#" data-target="#myModal" data-slide-to="2">
    <img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/3.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```